# ASP.Net Web API - How to restrict access to file in directory

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I wrote an Angular / ASP.Net Web API application that displays videos for a client.  The user must be authenticated before playing videos and the application works fine except that someone can still access any of the actual videos if they know the path and filename.  Is there a simple way to prevent someone from playing the video by just typing in: www.example.com/videos/thevideo1.mp4?

Comment: do you have iis security activated in your web.config?

Comment: The answer will vary based on the type of authorization schema you're using (ie Windows Integrated security (Active Directory) Vs. ASP.NET Membership provider Vs etc. etc.)  What security model is your app using?

Comment: I am using the [Authorize] attribute on the Web API classes.  The user logs in with a un/pw and gets a token which is presented to the Web API call in the header.

Comment: I do not have IIS Security activated in the web.config file.  Right now the app returns an error if the user tries to bypass the app and go directly to the directory of videos like: www.example.com/videos/.  But if they know the path and file name the video will play for them bypassing the token based authentication.  If IIS security would solve this issue could you tell me what to put in the web.config file?  Thank you.